# error in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am new to php. and I want to write some data to an excel file using php. I want to use PHPExcel for this purpose but I dont know how to do it I have downloaded and copes the to folders Clases and Expamles to my project folder then I tried 
`require_once "Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php"`
 `$objTpl = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("template.xlsx");`
 just these two lines but its showing an error canoy open the file then I created an excel file at the location `C:\wamp\www\scrapproj\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader` again it shows an error at another line. The error showing is 
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open tempplate.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.' in C:\wamp\www\scrapproj\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 82` 
 Please somebody hep me to solve this. 
**updated**
 Now I have updated my code like the following 
 `$objTpl = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("template1.xlsx");

        $objTpl->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2', 'PHPExcel');

     //   $filename=mt_rand(1,100000).'.xlsx';

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objTpl, 'Excel5');

        if(is_readable('template1.xlsx'))

        {

            $objWriter->save('template1.xlsx');

        }` 
Now its its running without any error. But after running the page I cant open the excel file directly its showing the error 
 `Excel canot open the file template1.xlsx because the file format or its extension is not valid`
 please help me to solve it

Comment: tempplate.xlsx is in the errorcode, but you are entering "template.xlsx" ?

Comment: oh sorry that was wrongly typed. Actually thats not the problem.

Comment: @user1767754 Is any other steps to do in the installation process which I am missing?

Comment: If PHPExcel can't open the file, then either the file isn't in the location you're specifying (like all filesystem functions in PHP, you need to tell PHPExcel where the file is in the filesystem as well as its name), or your script doesn't have permissions to access it. If you simply specify a filename with no path, PHPExcel will look in the current working directory, it will not search the entire disk system looking for that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the file in the current working directory, you can use the getcwd command to see what your working directory is.

1)

```
echo getcwd() . "\n";
```

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.getcwd.php

Furthermore check if you have permission on that file.

2)

```
is_readable($filename)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php

Comment: Thanks. Coped to the current working location. now when Im tring to save it showing an error Warning: fopen(template1.xlsx): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\scrapproj\Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE\PPS\Root.php on line 90 But my excel file's permission is set as unrestricted access. What is the problem now??

Comment: Instead of copying the file to your current working location, you can just change your current working location to where the file is with the **chdir('cvs');** command. look at the getcwd.php page i've listed you

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your updated question (in future, please close answered questions and ask a new question)

You're using the Excel5 Writer

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objTpl, 'Excel5');
```

Which is used for writing `BIFF` format files, which should have the extension `.xls`

But you're saving the file with a `.xlsx` extension

```
$objWriter->save('template1.xlsx');
```

which is for `OfficeOpenXML` format files

---

BIFF files are created using the Excel5 Writer, and have an extension of .xls

OfficeOpenXML files are created using the Excel2007 Writer, and have an extension of .xlsx

---

Don't mix and match, writers and extensions aren't interchangeable